# Why am I getting an Internal server error 500?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a [React](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/React_(JavaScript_library)) + Ruby on Rails project. I was trying to add some validation and error messages to my project. I made some changes while signing up. However, I’m getting *internal server error 500*.

The error is:

> SyntaxError (/Users/max/Development/code/Mod5/capstone/app/controllers/users_controller.rb:36: syntax error, unexpected `end', expecting end-of-input): \
>
> app/controllers/users_controller.rb:36: syntax error, unexpected `end', expecting end-of-input \ app/controllers/users_controller.rb:36: syntax error, unexpected` end', expecting end-of-input

Here is my code:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid, with: :render_unprocessable_entity_response
  skip_before_action :authorize, only: [:create]
    def create

        user = User.create!(user_params)

      if user
        session[:user_id] = user.id
        render json: user, status: :created
      else
        render json: { errors: ["That Email or Password isnt permitted."]}, status: :unauthorized
      end
    end


    end


    def show
      render json: @current_user
    end

    def index
      user=User.all
      render json: user
    end


  private
  def user_params
     params.permit(:name,:email,:password)

  end

  def render_unprocessable_entity_response(invalid)
    render json: { errors: invalid.record.errors.full_messages }, status: :unprocessable_entity
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your *create* method only needs two 'end's (one for the "def" tag and another for the "end" tag). Here you got three tags so one is getting you a syntax error.